# Hive Ambari Error: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask'

Tags: hive, ambari

I just run query join of two tables in Hive Ambari but getting error like this:

```
massage:
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
```

But if i run query select, its work. There is anyone can help me? Thank youu